# Angular 2+ - How to make an API call when user closes the browser window?

Tags: angular

How to make an API call when user closes the browser window?

// Code executed onbeforeunload

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('--start--');   
    // this call is not completing 
    this.remediationService.saveTime();
    console.log('---end---');
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "close" event that you can catch with today's browsers.

There is an onbeforeunload but you can't do a lot when it is called, especially you can't prevent the window closing without the user consent and most distant operations will fail if you try them from the page which is being closed.

One hacky trick you can use like firing the alert on onfeforeunload event and check whether your response came or not. If not, then fire alert again until your response came.

Note: Only alert, prompt are the way in JS where you can block the execution. I don't know whether there is any another solution but I know JS is single thread so we can't block the execution. Any call which is blocking, JS automatically execute it in asynchronous way.

Comment: OP wants to make an API call (probably to save the time when the users closed the window), not to prevent them from doing so.

Comment: When you close the browser, it just abort all the existing pending request and then close the window. So, In your case when you call the API in onbeforeunload, whether your request is in synchronous or asynchronous, the browser just abort your request and close the browser. No, chance you can get the API result until you block it.